# Add " SI or NO" in a Boolean field

Tags: sql, database, boolean

I have to store in the Boolean field the words " SI or NO " ( affirmation and negation in Spanish). But I can only use these:

TRUE: 
't'
'true'
'y'
'yes'
'on'
'1'

FALSE: 
'f'
'false'
'n'
'no'
'off'
'0'

```
create table sales

(

    code            varchar(3),
    sold            boolean,
CONSTRAINT pk_codesale PRIMARY KEY (code)

);
```

I try that:

```
insert into sales(code, sold) 
values('001','SI');
```

Edit:

Based on Python's post:

I try that code (based on AlexT82):

```
insert into sales(code, sold)  
(SELECT '001',CASE    
         WHEN 'FILLHERE' ='SI' THEN 't'
         ELSE 'f' END
);
```

Comment: what you mean `I have to store in the Boolean field the words " SI or NO "` boleean doesnt save string.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: which database are you using here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do this:

```
insert into sales(code, sold) 
 (SELECT '001',CASE 
             WHEN 'FILLHERE' ='SI' THEN 1
             ELSE 0 END
  );
```

Where in the part of 'FILLHERE' you fill the text where you fill "SI" or "NO" from your application.

Comment: single quote mean string ... I think you mean double quote `" ` to indicate a fieldname

Comment: No Juan, Python indicated he needed to put his insert into variables somehwere. i'm just cheating that code a bit to allow Python to enter just his 2 values in 2 places.... (so it's not a fieldname, but a string to be entered by the application of Python)

Comment: Yes somewhere variable mean `"" or @var` there you are using a constant. And if you have a constant you know the value and dont need a `case`

Comment: read my code in the following way: in Python's sample code he uses '001' and 'SI'. in my code, i've put these on the following 2 spots: '001', and 'FILLHERE'.  The assumption in my solution is that he gets the SI/NO from his application, and wants to store it as a boolean. Therefore, when inserting into the table, you could solve it with the insert statement i wrote.

Comment: I get this error:
ERROR: Column 'sold' is a boolean expression But the author is of type integer.Thanks for all the replies

Comment: change 1 to '1' and 0 to '0'

Comment: Now I get this error: ERROR: Column 'sold' is a boolean expression But the author is of type text.

Comment: change 1 to 't' and 0 to 'f'  (they indicate the value that is required in the boolean field. In MS SQL, you could have put 1 and 0, but apparently you are using a different SQL engine. So put whatever is accepted as true or false...)

Comment: Thank you very much for all your time , I have not gotten always gives me an error

Comment: can you post what code you are currently using ? As well as the database engine?

Answer (score 0):

I try that code:

```
insert into sales(code, sold) 

 (
  SELECT '001',CASE 

  WHEN 'FILLHERE' ='SI' THEN 't'

  ELSE 'f' END
 );
```

Comment: You should edit your question instead of adding an answer post (I just did it for you)

Answer (score 0):

As the error message indicates you need to CAST the CASE to BOOLEAN:

```
insert into sales(code, sold) 
values('001',cast(case when myVariable = 'NO' then 0 else 1 end as boolean));
```

Comment: Hello dnoeth with that command insert me in the table always by default " t". Thanks for the reply

Comment: @Python241820: As AlexT82 already stated, you can't *store* SI/NO in a boolean column, you can only translate it using a CASE (or you use `true`/`false` for insert). When you need to return SI/NO in a SELECT this is a display thing which is usually ahndled in the client/application (or you translate it back in your SELECT using `CASE WHEN sold THEN 'SI' ELSE 'NO' END`